# Rendering rooms in tornados redis chat

Tags: python, html, redis, tornado

I'm looking to add the rooms feature that comes with Brukva's Redis Tornado example except I'm attempting to implement the rooms in different pages on the website rather than having all the chats in one page. [Redis example](https://github.com/nellessen/Tornado-Redis-Chat)

**HTML**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li {% if room == 1 %}class="active"{% end %}><a href="/room/1">Room 1</a></li>
      <li {% if room == 2 %}class="active"{% end %}><a href="/room/2">Room 2</a></li>
      <li {% if room == 3 %}class="active"{% end %}><a href="/room/3">Room 3</a></li>
      <li {% if room == 4 %}class="active"{% end %}><a href="/room/4">Room 4</a></li>
      {% if not user %}<li class="active"><a href="/login">Sign In</a></li> {% end %}
      <!-- <li class="divider"></li> -->
      {% if user %}<li><a href="/logout">Sign Out</a></li> {% end %}
  </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="" style="font-size: 34px;">
    {% if room %}
      <h1>Room {{room}}</h1>
    {% else %}
      <h1>{{ apptitle }}</h1>
    {% end %}
    {% raw content %}
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Any suggestions as to how to add chats on different pages?

Comment: What do you mean with "except I'm attempting to implement the rooms in different pages on the website rather than having all the chats in one page"? Room 1 is located on /room/1 while room 2 is located on /room/2 and so on, which are all different pages.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means he wants the rooms on different pages as in "room/1.html", "room/2.html" rather than the sort of dynamic format as displayed above. OP after looking through the redis example, I think this involves more url remapping as opposed to simply changing the HTML/Python.